# Jquery/ move to another input

Tags: jquery

I have two input boxes: `A` and `B`.

I want to focus `B` automatically, only If the user insert to `A` the word:"bravo".

How can I do that? I try `outOfFuces`, but I need to click on other elemnt in order to focus B.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'move to B'? Give B focus, or actually move the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with [**.keyUp()**](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

```
$("#A").keyup(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "bravo") {
        $("#B").focus();
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `keyup()` event:

```
$('#a').on('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value == 'bravo') {
        $('#b').focus();
    }
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSt4v/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :
Assuming Id for textbox as inputA & inputB.

```
$("#inputA").blur(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "bravo") {
        $("#inputB").focus();
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **keyup** effect for input text 'A' and check for your word like

```
$('#A').on('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value == 'bravo') {
      $('#B').focus();   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code,

```
$('.A').keydown(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
     if($('.A').val() == 'bravo'){
         $('.B').focus();
      }
    }, 50);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

HTML:

```
<label for="A">A</label>
<input id="A" type="text" />
<br />
<label for="B">B</label>
<input id="B" type="text" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#A").keyup(function(){
   if($("#A").val() == "bravo"){
      $("#B").focus();
   }
});
```